# jms - upgrading WebSphereMQ JMS client 5.3 to 7

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I have a JMS client that runs with 5.3 WebSphereMQ libraries and runs fine. I tried to upgrade WebSphereMQ JMS libraries to 7.5 and got the following exception:

```
 MQJMS2008: failed to open MQ queue ''.; nested exception is 
 com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'.!
```

This one comes up when I try to access an `MQQueue` instance. I read up on the Internet that this one is a "NOT_AUTORISED" error. But with 5.3 we didn't use any credentials and it worked. I also read that there is a system property `com.ibm.mq.jms.ForceUserID` which controls whether `MQConnectionFactory` sends current user ID or just empty string, but changing this property didn't do anything for me.

Let me also say that I have no control over queue manager and the administrators are reluctant to give any details. Maybe it's something simple that can be fixed by changing some simple property?

Comment: What is the queue manager version? is that also v7.5?

Comment: Yes, It's 2035 - MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED issue. Have you checked where the JMS Client is running..this m/c might not have access to queues. - You need to check with MQ admin team on this. They might have setup block ip list.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the properties of the channel used to connect to the queue manager. Both SVRCONN and CLNTCONN if define.  Is there a MCAUSER(userid) defined in that channel which is available in the machine with 7.5 qmgr? This userid should be given permissions to connect to the queue manager and put/get permissions to the queue.

Are you sure if there is any channel exit overriding the user setup.

There are lot of changes between 5.3 and 7.5.  Make sure the channel used by the application doesn't connect as mqm but as another user.

The MQ Administrators must provide support in this scenario (an administrator myself).  You cant fix this on your own.